# whats wrong in iPad running iOS 9.2.1 and an iPhone running iOS 9.2.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, ipad

> My app rejected due to this problem .
>
> we discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an iPad running iOS 9.2.1 and an iPhone running iOS 9.2.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> Unable to login through Facebook, an error occurs
>
> Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise
>   and resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in the Resolution Center to provide information on how
>   these features were intended to work.

This is My info.plist

[image]

I am using fb login because of this any problem , i need some one help now give me a best solution.

Comment: I think you should provide TLS version and NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads for FB in Transport Security Policy.

Comment: can you explain about it little bit clear bro @HardikShekhat .

Comment: See this links for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http?noredirect=1#comment52543453_31254725. You get an idea from there.

Comment: Checkout again the SDK of Login with Facebook again, it may be a problem because of old Facebook SDK you are using, or the developer account of Facebook is still in developer mode instead of distributed/publish mode.

Comment: @Hima my fb sdk is 4.7.0 ,and its in publish mode.